# np array inside list to compute mean

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to compute the mean of each nested list in the following:

```
import numpy as np
centroids = [[[3, 2]], [[2, 3], [3, 4], [2, 3]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]]
```

So I want these the column mean of the following:
`[3, 2]`, `[[2, 3], [3, 4], [2, 3]] = [2.3, 3.3]` and `[[1, 2], [3, 4]] = [2, 3]`

I tried to do:

```
for c in centroids:
    c = np.mean(np.array(c), axis=0)
```

But it doesn't work, nothing changes in the centroids list. How to do it?

Comment: So you you want a list of the means of the pairs, of the mean of all the numbers, or what?

Comment: "nothing changes in the centroids list" -- why should anything change, you only read it and you don't do anything with the result of `mean`...

Comment: @256Bits pairs as explained with `=`

Comment: @DanMašek Sorry, corrected it, and still!

Comment: Ok, well you're resetting the value of `c`, not changing list it currently represents. Do `c[:] = np.mean(np.array(c), axis=0)`

Comment: Adding to what Dan said, yes, the value of c is being resetted everytime, but I'd rather have a new list to hold the mean value of each centroid, so, instantiate a `centroid_mean = []` then in the loop you just, `centroid_mean.append(np.mean(np.array(c), axis=0))`

Comment: You could probably reduce it to `centroids = list(map(lambda c: np.mean(c, axis=0), centroids))`... or something along those lines.

Comment: @DanMašek I really didn't get the logic of `C[:]` can you explain this gently?

Comment: Search for "Python slice assignment". It's a special syntax for lists. `a[:] = b` means replace the entire contents of the list `a` with `b`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use simple list comprehension to collect means:

```
centroids = [np.mean(a, 0).tolist() for a in centroids]
```

---

```
[[3.0, 2.0], [2.3333333333333335, 3.3333333333333335], [2.0, 3.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

A vanilla python implementation:

```py
centroids = [[[3, 2]], [[2, 3], [3, 4], [2, 3]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]]
means = list()
for centroid in centroids:
    pair = [0, 0]
    for centroidPair in centroid:
        pair[0] += centroidPair[0]
        pair[1] += centroidPair[1]
    pair[0] /= len(centroid)
    pair[1] /= len(centroid)
    means.append(pair);
print(means);
```

It outputs the expected result:

```
[[3.0, 2.0], [2.3333333333333335, 3.3333333333333335], [2.0, 3.0]]
```

Comment: Nobody likes Vanilla anything nowadays!